# Checkbox is not showing in html/css

Tags: html, css, web

I am using an external css from a theme, but whenever I put a checkbox, it shows for a split second and then it directly disappears.

My code:

```
<div class="css-checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox1" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox"  value="1" name="attended" />
       <label for="checkbox1" class="css-label">Attended</label>
    </div>
```

For more info about the files : [HERE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7AAH5GRouFnVGhob2xfcWtMN2M?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sounds like a JS plugin could be hiding the checkbox, are you using any third-party JS libraries?

Comment: I have edited the post with more info added. I am using a third-party everything :P (javascript, css, etc.)

Comment: Wow, there are a huge amount of JS files there, if I were you I would start by commenting out the JS files in your HTML and seeing if that fixes the issue, then 1 by 1 add the JS files back in to see which one is causing the problem. Its very difficult for anyone here to give you an accurate answer with such a huge amount of code to look through and no working example. You could also try creating a JSFiddle to demo your issue

Comment: From looking at your screenshots it looks like the icheck plugin could well be causing your problem, check the plugin website for help and docs: http://icheck.fronteed.com/

Comment: Will do, thanks for the help man. :D

Answer (score 1):

Check your CSS panel for any overwrites. The split second tells me that initially it's visible but some other file overwrites it on a later moment, when that file is loaded. Ideally we should be able to see all your code to verify what is wrong.

You can find your css panel by pressing F12 or navigating to your developer tools and inspect the element.

Comment: Exactly you could add screenshot from elements style at developers tool

Comment: Hey man, I have just uploaded the files and screenshots to a public Google Drive folder [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7AAH5GRouFnVGhob2xfcWtMN2M?usp=sharing) . Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: If you check the isCheckbox class, you'll notice that it's being set to position absolute by your plugins.min.css . This is causing the hiding. I'm not sure if it's intentional but I don't think so. You can see it yourself in screenshot 1.png

Comment: I dug deep into this file, and found a lot of checkbox stuff. I deleted the position absolute, and nothing happened. Is it possible to help me out through team viewer and skype ? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the CSS property z-index, that allows you to put an element over the others, try the following:

```
your_checkbox {
    z-index: +1;
}
```